# Prevent flickering of visible UICollectionView cells

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using an infinite scrolling UICollectionView which is bound to a custom ObservableCollection which is in the ViewModel. The cell has only a UITextView which is databound to a string attribute in the model object.

When I start scrolling down I am displaying more items by calling the AddRange on the OservableCollection.

```
public class MyCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public MyCollection()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public MyCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
    }

    public MyCollection(List<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        foreach (var item in range)
        {             
            Items.Add(item);
        }

        var dispatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMainThreadDispatcher>();
        dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(() =>
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, range));
        });
    }
}
```

The new items are added successfully, however once the collectionview  get´s reloaded from the notification change event the visible cell items may flicker and show the wrong data for a split second. Is it possible to prevent the flickering of the visible cells when loading more data into the UICollectionView?

Comment: Are you reloading the whole collectionview?  Don't do that. Just add the news cells

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the suggestions. Yes, I asume the propertyChangeEvent triggers reloading of the whole collectionview. Do you know how I can only trigger the reload of the new cells which are not visible? I could call collectionView.ReloadItems(indexPaths[]) but I don't know how I can retrieve the indexpaths for the new items.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `IndexPath[]` array to pass into `collectionView.ReloadItems(indexPaths[])` by doing this:

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...

    var originalCount = Count;

    foreach (var item in range)
    {             
        Items.Add(item);
    }

    List<NSIndexPath> reloadPaths = new List<NSIndexPath>();
    for (int i = originalCount; i < Count-1; i++) {
        reloadPaths.Add(NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(i, 0));
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then you can execute `collectionView.ReloadItems(reloadPaths.ToArray())`